# Flutter getting error while getting data from json type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String,dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I need help. I am getting error while converting api json data to dart

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String,dynamic>'

here is the code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Network {
  Future<Apitojson> getdata() async {
    var finalurl = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/var";
    // var finalurl = "http://192.168.18.6:5000/users"; //for real mobile device
    return http.get(Uri.parse(finalurl)).then((http.Response response) {
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400) {
        throw Exception("Error while fetching data");
      }
      print("Response body: ${response.statusCode}");
      //actual mapped model
      return Apitojson.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)[0]);
    });
  }
}

class Apitojson {
  CleanTweets? cleanTweets;
  CleanTweets? orignalTweets;
  CleanTweets? polarity;
  int? totalTweets;

  Apitojson(
      {this.cleanTweets, this.orignalTweets, this.polarity, this.totalTweets});

  Apitojson.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    cleanTweets = json['CleanTweets'] != null
        ? CleanTweets.fromJson(json['CleanTweets'])
        : null;
    orignalTweets = json['OrignalTweets'] != null
        ? CleanTweets.fromJson(json['OrignalTweets'])
        : null;
    polarity = json['Polarity'] != null
        ? CleanTweets.fromJson(json['Polarity'])
        : null;
    totalTweets = json['TotalTweets'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (cleanTweets != null) {
      data['CleanTweets'] = cleanTweets!.toJson();
    }
    if (orignalTweets != null) {
      data['OrignalTweets'] = orignalTweets!.toJson();
    }
    if (polarity != null) {
      data['Polarity'] = polarity!.toJson();
    }
    data['TotalTweets'] = totalTweets;
    return data;
  }
}

class CleanTweets {
  String? s0;
  String? s1;
  String? s2;
  String? s3;
  String? s4;
  String? s5;

  CleanTweets({this.s0, this.s1, this.s2, this.s3, this.s4, this.s5});

  CleanTweets.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    s0 = json['0'];
    s1 = json['1'];
    s2 = json['2'];
    s3 = json['3'];
    s4 = json['4'];
    s5 = json['5'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['0'] = s0;
    data['1'] = s1;
    data['2'] = s2;
    data['3'] = s3;
    data['4'] = s4;
    data['5'] = s5;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and here is the main file code

```
// import 'package:draw_graph/draw_graph.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'gettingapi.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late Future<Apitojson> netobj;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    netobj = Network().getdata();
    // netobj.then((value) => print(value.polarity!.negative));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sentiment Analysis'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
        children: [
          FutureBuilder<Apitojson>(
            future: netobj,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                Apitojson? polarity = snapshot.data;
                Apitojson? tweet = snapshot.data;
                Apitojson? fetchedTweets = tweet;
                return Column(
                  // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                  children: [
                    Text(polarity!.polarity.toString()),
                    Text(tweet!.cleanTweets.toString()),
                    Text(fetchedTweets!.toString()),
                  ],
                );
                // return Text(snapshot.data!.polarity!.negative.toString());
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am expecting to convert my api json data to dart so that i can show it to my app

my api output is like this

```
{
"CleanTweets": {
    "0": "rt it s coming",
    "1": "rt it s look at how good i am you suck versus wow you re really good at the game got any tips ppl posturi",
    "2": "how horny do you have to be to rt porn on twitter",
    "3": "rt warmth in the snow 1 2 longer hair on macaque is growing on meeee lmk legomonkiekid monkiekid shadowpea",
    "4": "rt morning sunshine gulf shopeetakeover 1212shopeegulf gulfkanawut",
    "5": "rt ipo adda sulavineyards ipo opens for subscription as the company aims to raise rs 960 crore at a price band of rs 340 rs"
},
"OrignalTweets": {
    "0": "RT @IrenaBuzarewicz: It's coming ,
    "1": "RT @JimmyCrckedCorn: @Curr It’s “look at how good I am, you suck,” versus, “wow, you’re really good at the game. Got any tips?” Ppl posturi…",
    "2": "how horny do you have to be to rt porn on twitter \n#广州 #广州线下 ,
    "3": "RT @KibblesCreation: Warmth in the snow ❄️ 1/2\n\nLonger hair on macaque is growing on meeee (°▽°)\n\n#LMK #LEGOMonkieKid #MonkieKid #shadowpea…",
    "4": "RT @GulfPhiB: Morning sunshine \n\nGulf ShopeeTakeover\n#1212ShopeeGULF @gulfkanawut #GulfKanawut #กลัฟคณาวุฒิ\n\n,
    "5": "RT @bqprime: #IPO Adda | #SulaVineyards’ #IPO opens for subscription as the company aims to raise Rs 960 crore at a price band of Rs 340-Rs…"
},
"Polarity": {
    "0": "Neutral",
    "1": "positive",
    "2": "Neutral",
    "3": "Neutral",
    "4": "Neutral",
    "5": "Neutral"
},
"TotalTweets": 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you put your stacktrace please and/or json ? Have you checked the content of `json.decode(response.body)[0]` ?

It looks like nullable field aren't checked, especially `s1,s2,s3`... from `CleanTweets` attributes are nullable and you should add `as String?` with`json['xx']` in `CleanTweets.fromJson`.

```
class CleanTweets {
  String? s0;
  String? s1;
  String? s2;
  String? s3;
  String? s4;
  String? s5;

  CleanTweets({this.s0, this.s1, this.s2, this.s3, this.s4, this.s5});

  CleanTweets.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    s0 = json['0'] as String?;
   ...
}
```

May i suggest you to use a tool to generate your class from the json. You can use [json to dart](https://jsontodart.com/) or something like.

Besides give a try to `response.bodyBytes` to get your result.

```
  Map<String, dynamic> decodedResponse = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)) ;
  Apitojson result = Apitojson.fromJson(decodedResponse);
```

Comment: i have used that jason to dart but still go the same problem

Comment: What about json.decode(response.body)[0] ? Why are you checking only first index of the result ? Is it normal ?

Comment: same response with 0 or without zero

Comment: i have updated my question where i added my api output also kindly check that

Comment: see the last part of my answer -> response.bodyBytes utf8 decode, it should be that